# How to block columns in a file

Tags: column, access, access-denied, edit, excel-web-access-webpart

How can I block specific columns so that they're visible for others, but people cannot edit this (specific) column in sharepoint? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Permissions are not given by columns, they are given by item. So, if you don't want a user to edit a certain item/list you have to change the permissions on that item/list.

Here is how to do this:
[Edit permissions for a list, library, or individual item](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Edit-permissions-for-a-list-library-or-individual-item-5b900de3-9123-41c9-aa04-919ae6606d40)